# Will Upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to Kubuntu 18.04 Erase my Data?

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

Hello AskUbuntu community, I recently installed Kubuntu onto a bootable drive and tested it out and I really enjoyed it. Before upgrading I would like to know if I would lose my data.

I am currently running Ubuntu 17.10 with the Plasma KDE and I am not sure if moving from Ubuntu to Kubuntu will remove my settings. I have spent some time modifying my themes, packages, and other system settings that I would like to keep.

Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind upgrades are mor complicated than fresh installs and more things "break". You should do a trial upgrade on a copy of your data first and test everything you can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Kubuntu to 18.04 will not destroy your data or settings. In fact if you have installed the kde-desktop package you are already using Kubuntu. However, as with every update it is prudent to take a backup before updating.